# Query last 30 days but keeping days with no result/value

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sum

I have the following function to fetch the points count of each day from the past 30 days. This query only fetches the days where there is a value available, if there were no points awarded on that day it doesn't fetch anything. How do i get it to show all days regardless of whether any points were gained on that day?

**For example:**

31st May - 30 points.
30st May - 0 points.
29st May - 5 points.
28st May - 10 points.
27st May - 0 points.
...

**Instead of:**

31st May - 30 points.
29st May - 5 points.
28st May - 10 points.
...

```
SELECT date_added, SUM(points) 
FROM points_table pt, userCake_Users u 
WHERE pa.date_added >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ) 
AND u.user_id = '" . $user_id . "' 
AND u.user_id = pt.user_id 
GROUP BY date(pt.date_added)");
```

Comment: This sort of task is often more suited to your application code... why not just assume 0 if the date is not present in the resultset?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cannot generate the missing dates out of thin air. Therefor, my suggestion would be to create a seperate table (maybe of engine MEMORY) and insert the queries dates into there. Then you can join on your base table as above:

```
select date_added,
(select sum(points_table.points) from points_table where points_table.date_added = inmemorytable.date_added) as "Points"
from inmemorytable
inner join userCake_Users u on u.u.user_id = '" . $user_id . "' AND u.user_id = pt.user_id
```

Not tested as I do not have these structures at hand. The inner join and the subquery may make trouble and you might have to switch them around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *temporary table* in memory in this case and fill it out with zeros where necessary.

I have written next routine:

```
SET @start_date = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS RawResults;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE RawResults ENGINE = MEMORY
SELECT date, SUM(test.table.points)
FROM test.table
WHERE test.table.date >= @start_date
GROUP BY test.table.date;

SET @cur_date = @start_date;    
WHILE @cur_date <= CURDATE() DO    
    IF NOT EXISTS (select * from RawResults where date = @cur_date) THEN
        INSERT INTO RawResults VALUES (@cur_date, 0);
    END IF;        
    SET @cur_date =  DATE_ADD(@cur_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END WHILE;

SELECT *
FROM RawResults
ORDER BY date DESC;
```